# how to setup path tinymce in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, tinymce

Here is my controller

```
if( $request->hasFile('file') ) {
    $image       = $request->file;
    $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $filename = str_random(30).'.'.$extension;            
    $image_resize = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
    $a =  public_path().'/images/content/'.$filename;
        if($a) {
            return response()->json([
                'location' =>  $a
            ]);
        }
}
```

And it store img path

../../../../../../../../Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/public/images/content2e7KZeeBDd1WuQhy8Y48ULzJTSzFbP.jpg

how to remove all ../ or how to set up path in laravel i try to use

```
  $a = asset('images/content/'.$filename);
```

but it store path ../../ I need to store full path not ../ how can i fix this

Comment: What path is your target? Is it the public?

Comment: Why do you need the full path instead of the relative path?

Comment: I want this path Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/public/images/content/imgname @Jonjie

Comment: You just have to locate to your `public` folder right? Why do you need that full path?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [`realpath()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) function:

```
    if($a) {
        return response()->json([
            'location' =>  realpath($a)
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: its return {"location":false}

Comment: By looking at your code i am guessing that you are not using $a to save the resized image, thus the file is never created, only the path